# Identical function returns different values depending if created in-console or from module

Tags: json, function, powershell, module

I have a function within a PowerShell module that is returning a different value than if I define that function within the console and then run it.

I'm trying to replace the trailing comma in a JSON variable (otherwise the JSON is invalid).
When declared from the console, this function performs flawlessly. But once inside my module, and imported, it does not.

Here is the function:

```bsh
Function Format-Something {
     $myJSON =
'{
     "command": "test",
     "something": "else",
}'
     $myJSON.Replace(",`n}","`n}")
}
```

Here is an example showing the exact same code in my editor, and in the powershell window.

[image: Screenshot imgur link]

I initially load the module, and run the function. It does **not** run as intended. I then copy and paste the same function code into the console and it **does** work correctly.

I assume this has something to do with new line formatting. But I've tried basing my replace off both `` `r`n `` and `` `n `` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut tells me that when it is saved in a module that there is a carriage return *and* line feed in the saved file. So your match string is not being tested against the exact same text.

Switching to a regex replacement could make this seemless. `` ",`r?`n\}" `` should work as the carriage return is optional (as denoted by the `?`). However your are really saying any comma followed by whitespace and a closing brace should have the comma removed so lets just do that.

```
'{
     "command": "test",
     "something": "else",
}' -replace ",\s+}", "`r`n}"
```

So we replace any comma, followed by whitespace. You could take this farther with lookaheads but I wanted to keep it simple.

**Note:** this could cause a cosmetic issue if you have nested json and also not find certain issues if you are not following formatting conventions. e.g.

```
{
     "command": "test",
     "nested": [{"Test":1234},]
     "something": "else",}
```

This purely helps understand why what you were doing was acting the way it was (assuming I'm right of course.)

Comment: Thanks! This works from both the module and the CLI. It is also very simple. Marking as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
Function Format-Something {
    $myJSON =
'{
    "command": "test",
    "something": "else",
}'
    $myJSON.Replace(",$([Environment]::NewLine)}","$([Environment]::NewLine)}")
}
```

And a little bit more robust:

```
[RegEx]::Replace($myJSON, "\s*,\s*$([Environment]::NewLine)\s*}", "$([Environment]::NewLine)}", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline)
```

Comment: Funnily enough this causes the opposite effect. It works perfectly from within the module (which is preferably), but no longer works when declared from the CLI. I will check if the other solution works on both before deciding which to mark as the answer. Either way, thanks !!